# Anchor tags for search results in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've created a search that is querying multiple tables in a database. I'm trying change the href for each result, but obviously they have different routes/controllers. I added a custom attribute in the query:

```
$enterprise = DB::table('enterprise')
                    ->selectRaw("'enterprise.show' as link")
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
$entertainment = DB::table('entertainment')
                    ->selectRaw("'entertainment.show' as link")
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
```

Which works when I union the queries with the rest. I then have a foreach loop in my view:

```
@foreach($results as $r)
                <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 20px">
                    <div class="hpanel">
                        <div class="panel-body text-center h-200">
                            <a style="color: #3c763d" href="{{route($r->link, $r->id)}}">
                                <h4 class="font-extra-bold no-margins text-success">{{Str::limit($r->name, 15)}}</h4></a>
                            <small>{{ Str::limit($r->description, 50) }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <i class="fa fa-gbp"><p style="display: inline"> {{$r->cost}}</p></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

But this gives me undefined property $r->id. So, I add in another select to my controller ->select('id', 'name' et al) and then I get undefined property $link.

I have no idea how to link each result to their relevant route/controller. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because you need to add the other columns in the select portion of your eloquent query.

Something like:

`selectRaw("id, name, enterprise.show as link")`

Comment: thanks, it was selectRaw("'enterprise.show' as link, id, name, description"). the variables any other way throw a constraint violation